# Is this code realy XSS proof?

Tags: php, regex, validation, xss, user-input

I have the following php XSS filter function:

```
<?php
function xssfilter($inp){
    $inp = html_entity_decode(urldecode($inp));
    $inp = preg_replace('/!/','',$inp);
    if (preg_match('/script|on|xmlns|data/iu',$inp)){
        while(preg_match('/script|on|xmlns|data/iu',$inp)){
            $inp = preg_replace('/(script)|(on)|(xmlns)|(data)/iu','NO!',$inp);
        }
    }
    return $inp;
}
?>
```

Obviously you can upload a remote script here but my question here is if you can bypass the regex in some way?

Comment: This question sounds like a trivia question.

Comment: It looks like the person, who wrote the function, did not have a very good understanding of how to sanitize content. URL decode, entity decode, replace exclamation mark, replace afew keywords... Looks like they just threw things at the problem, hoping that it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

No, this has at least one immediately obvious flaw. You can insert a link tag containing JavaScript like so:

```
<a href="&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x36;&#x41;&#x3B;&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x36;&#x31;&#x3B;&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x37;&#x36;&#x3B;&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x36;&#x31;&#x3B;&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x37;&#x33;&#x3B;&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x36;&#x33;&#x3B;&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x37;&#x32;&#x3B;&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x36;&#x39;&#x3B;&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x37;&#x30;&#x3B;&#x26;&#x23;&#x78;&#x37;&#x34;&#x3B;: alert('XSS');">Innocent Link</a>
```

The only thing stopping this attack in Chrome is the fact it has built in XSS protection. Your XSS protection doesn't stop it.